# Accessing html textbox and label data in codebehind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam using html control in mysite (idon't want to use asp controls).problem here i'am unable to get the data in label and textbox in codebehind c#
he is my html controls

```
<form runat="server" class="sainex_form1">
    <input id="txtDateTime" runat="server" value="" type="text"  datetime="datetime" />
    <label id="lblJobCity" runat="server">
</form>
<p class="button-row">
    <input class="btn-submit" runat="server" type="image" name="image" id="Image4"   onclick="UpdateActivity()" />
</p>
```

in updateActivity() i'm sending values to c# using jquery AJAX

and im using this code in C#

for textbox:

```
string a=txtDateTime.Value;
```

for label:

```
string b=lblJobCity.InnerText;
```

from above to i'm getting empty value and i also tried

```
Request.Form["lblJobCity"].ToString();
```

but no result plz suggest me on this

Comment: `Request.Form["lblJobCity"].ToString();` actually gave you *no result*? Not a null reference exception?

Comment: yes im getting null reference exception @Andrew

Comment: Do you have values in the controls?

Comment: I think we need to see your `<form>` tag. Oh, and by the way; You can't use `Request.Form` to access the information on the `<label>` at all. And finally; do you have ViewState disabled?

Comment: i'm unable to use <form> because not submitting the entire form.and  can i get the values without using form tag? @Anderw

Comment: Can you show more code (html & code behind)?

Comment: You don't need any runat=server for Ajax calls. You do need to post ur jquery code and server-side receiving code.

Comment: idon't have problem with AJAX but i want to get the data in control in c# through server side code @YuriyGalanter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value of html controls in C# code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963058/getting-value-of-html-controls-in-c-sharp-code-behind)

Answer (score 1):

Do put some values in the controls: E.g.

```
<input id="txtDateTime" runat="server" value="2014-12-12" type="text" datetime="datetime"/>
<label id="lblJobCity" runat="server">Some Text goes here </label>
```

Then `txtDateTime.Value` and `lblJobCity.InnerText` will provide data server-side

*UPDATE* Here's complete form to make it work:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

   <input id="txtDateTime" runat="server" value="" type="text" datetime="datetime"  />
   <label id="lblJobCity" runat="server">Seattle</label>

   <input type="submit" id="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="submit_ServerClick" />
</form>
```

And then check the values in the event:

```
protected void submit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = txtDateTime.Value;
    string b = lblJobCity.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: then i'm getting the data  i've given in html not the value i entered in input

Comment: Input should appear as well, but on submit. E.g. add `<input type="submit" />` to those controls and check values upon clicking button (I've updated my answer to a small runnable sample)

Comment: Isn't the submit_ServerClick a control?

Comment: plz see my edited answer i'm using jquery AJAX to communicate with code behind

Comment: submit_ServerClick is an event handler for submit button.  But @user1943217 heavily modified the question, there wasn't any mention of AJAX before. Or form construct.  So I sense downvotes coming.